# How to start and stop loop with a button and pause on start

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Hi have script as below and the problem is that after one loop it stops playing. I would like to if i hold button down to play all the time and after i release mouse button it should stop playing.

```
    stop();
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

function play_start(event:MouseEvent):void
{
   play();
}


function play_stop(event:MouseEvent):void
{
   stop();
}
left.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, play_start);
left.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, play_stop);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could either use a TimerEvent or an EnterFrame event for this.

Here's how it would work with EnterFrame.

```
var btn;//your button

btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, play_start);
btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, play_stop);

function play_start(event:MouseEvent):void{
    addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, loopdeloop);
}

function play_stop(event:MouseEvent):void{
    removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, loopdeloop);
}

function loopdeloop(event:Event):void{
 //do stuff
}
```

keep in mind, the loopdeloop will execute every frame of your swf, which mean if your swf is at 30 Frames per second, the loopdeloop function will be called 30 times a second.

See also : [EnterFrame](http://www.actionscriptmoron.com/AS3Tutorials/events-enterframe/)

[TimerEvent](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/TimerEvent.html)

PS: if you use TimerEvent, you should start() and stop() your timer object in the play_start() and play_stop() functions.